# Which data provider do you recommend?

Tags: data, backtesting, optimization

i need to run optimization models and backtests on developed market equities. I have access to Refinitivs Eikon, but it doesnt have a backtest tool and downloading the data is a challenge on his own. I know little to nothing about other sources, which one would yo recommend?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a recommendation on traditional data providers which give you Fundamental data, prices and the like out-of-the-box. Hopefully with the option to download such data so i can run diferent optimization methods.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Juanito, it seems like you're not really just looking for a data provider then?  but rather a provider of data, backtesting and analysis tools

Comment: Well, if i had the data i could run the Backtest and Analysis, but, as you said @Chris, both solutions could work. The only drawback of having the Backtest and analysis tools on the provider is that i wont be able to run all the optimization methods i need.

Comment: OK, well the linked to thread is about as good as it gets then, particularly if you're not looking to go the traditional industry (ie, expensive) route of TR Worldscope, Compustat, Factset or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/data). I believe they offer all that you are looking for.

ps.: I have no affiliation with the company or anyone working there.

Comment: It looks promising! I'll check it out before accepting the answer. Either way, thanks!! :D